# Titanium Android module for enable/disable data connection

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

Has anyone found a way to enable/disable data connection on Android? 
Is there any module in Titanium to enable/disable data connection programmatically?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try browsing through http://gitt.io. It is a listing of all Titanium modules available on github.

Comment: Thanx for fast replay.